# Do custom container iterators guarantee ADL to consider namespace std?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std, argument-dependent-lookup

I have no intention of using this in real code. I promise.

Does the standard guarantee that `std` namespace is going to be found when a function argument is of type `container::iterator` and `container::iterator` isn't a `typedef` for a built-in type?

For example

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
   std::set<int> s;
   find(s.begin(), s.end(), 0); //do I have a guarantee that std::find will be found?
}
```

In other words, can the iterator class be defined in such a namespace that `std` won't be considered by ADL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the answer is **no** in the most general case, but **yes** for most practical implementations.

According to the C++ ISO standard, §3.4.2/2, there is a notion of an "associated namespace" for an argument, which is defined in a way that includes

> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; **the class of which it is a
>   member, if any**; and its direct and indirect base classes. **Its associated namespaces are the namespaces
>   in which its associated classes are defined.**

This suggests that if the iterator type is really a nested type inside of some container like `std::set`, then an associated namespace for that iterator in the call to `find` would be `std`, since `std::set` is an associated class and `std` is the namespace containing `set`.  The standard then says that (§3.4.2/2a)

> If the ordinary unqualified lookup of the name finds the declaration of a class member function, the associated namespaces and classes are not considered. Otherwise **the set of declarations found by the lookup of the function name is the union of the set of declarations found using ordinary unqualified lookup and the set
>   of declarations found in the namespaces and classes associated with the argument types**.

This would mean that you would indeed find the `find` function in `namespace std`.

However, this is *not* guaranteed to work in general.  We also have from the spec (§3.4.2) that

> Typedef names and using-declarations used to specify the types do not contribute to this set.

So, as you mentioned in your question, if the iterator type is some sort of `typedef`, this isn't guaranteed to work correctly.  But barring that, it appears that if you know that the type is not a typedef, it has to be in `namespace std` or nested in a class in `namespace std` and should get picked up for ADL.  **But don't do it!** :-)

Comment: `set_iterator` would also have to be in `namespace std` because "All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace std or namespaces nested within namespace std".  However, if the container were a vector and the iterator was a typedef for a raw pointer as Peter mentioned in hos answer (I understand that was sometimes the case in early vector implementations - I suspect it's not common) I think you'd run into the problem you describe.

Comment: @Michael Burr- Thanks so much for bringing this to my attention!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Early libstdc++ used `typedef pointer iterator` for `std::vector` before they replaced it with `std::__normal_iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

The exact type of `::iterator` etc. for the standard containers is *implementation-defined*, so in theory there's nothing stopping it from being a `typedef` to something outside of `std::` (e.g. a plain pointer).

I can't find anything else in the standard that suggests that ADL will always work in this case, so -- unless someone corrects me -- I'm going to have to say that the answer is: no, you can't assume that `find` will be found via ADL.